# Laplace's Method Integration

Tags: integration, asymptotics, laplace-transform, complex-integration

Consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I_n(x)=\int^2_1 (\log_{e}t) e^{-x(t-1)^{n}} \, dt
\end{equation}
Use Laplace's Method to show that 
\begin{equation}
I_n(x) \sim \frac{1}{nx^\frac{2}{n}} \int^\infty_0 \tau^{\frac{2-n}{n}} e^{-\tau} \, d\tau \end{equation}
as $x\rightarrow\infty$.
where $0<n\leq2$. Hence find the leading order behaviour of $I_1(x)$. and $I_2(x)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

=>
Its really difficult question for me.

Here, $g(t) = -(t-1)^{n}$ has the maximum at $t=0$

but $h(t)= \log_{e} t$ at $t=0$, $h(0)=0$. 
so I can not go any further. PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: A [related technique](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F270628%2Flaplaces-method&ei=E2LwUaWSHJSh4AOm34GoCA&usg=AFQjCNFwxfgrIvRSCW-D5rmriEGiAHn4pg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s=x(t-1)^n$. We then get $t = 1 + \left(\dfrac{s}x\right)^{1/n}$. We get $dt = \dfrac1{x^{1/n}} \dfrac{s^{1/n-1}}n ds$. Hence,
$$I_n(x) = \int_1^2 \ln t \cdot e^{-x(t-1)^n}dt = \int_0^x \ln \left(1+\left(\dfrac{s}x \right)^{1/n}\right) e^{-s} \dfrac1{x^{1/n}} \dfrac{s^{1/n-1}}n ds$$
Hence,
$$I_n(x) = \dfrac1{nx^{1/n}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{x^{k/n}} \int_0^x s^{k/n} s^{1/n-1} e^{-s}ds$$
Hence, as $x \to \infty$ and keeping only the leading order term, we get
$$I_n(x) \sim \dfrac1{nx^{1/n}} \dfrac1{x^{1/n}} \int_0^{\infty} s^{1/n} s^{1/n-1} e^{-s}ds = \dfrac1{nx^{2/n}}\int_0^{\infty} s^{2/n-1}e^{-s}ds$$